# lost proportions when changed hosting services

Tags: website, compatibility, hosting

I hosted site while I was developing it here
https://ligular-blankets.000webhostapp.com/
when work was done I sent it to client and he uploaded it to his site at
https://master-mind.co/form/FirstStep.html
All looks same to me, did not lose any proportions or anything.I stent it to my friends none of them have any differences, but he keeps complaining that it is taking more space and lost proportions. I also tried all browsers and mobile, all is 100% same. He tried other browsers and mobile and sayed everywhere is broken. Please help what is the problem?

Comment: Is he aware that responsive design will reformat to fit the client's viewport? Get him to send screenshots. Both respond the same for me, up to the signup page [ I obviously didn't go any further]

Comment: He did it does looks different

Comment: then you're going to have to try repro on a similar setup. Is he on some ancient browser or OS?

Comment: Yes he is (Ancient chrome) but problem is when I hosted site It looked good to him, now when he is hosting proportions changed.

Comment: Tell him to try a current browser. If it's that ancient, how many people are still using it... & how many would care?  ;)